# Treasure hunt question

Tags: riddle, word, treasure-hunt

A series of numbers is given in the question and it could be anything. Have tried  things related to temperature values etc. but none worked.

Guessing the next number in this series looks highly unlikely.

```
16 18 20 62
```

Hint: Answer is a 7 letter word.

Comment: +2, +2, +2, +22, +22, +22, +222... probably 84 with my logic

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this didnt work

Comment: Looks like this isn't a mathematic series question. Maybe something which these numbers represent.

Comment: Can you give us the whole question?

Comment: @bleh this is the entire question. Only these numbers are given. We need to figure out what they represent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it is

> **Sarcasm**
>  These are the atomic numbers of the elements with symbols  S = 16 Ar = 18 Ca = 20 Sm = 62